# Nested GLKViewController

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I am trying to nest a `GLKView` inside a `UIView` XIB.  Basically following the steps here:
[Nested GLKView and GLKViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244525/nested-glkview-and-glkviewcontroller)

My **CustomOpenGLController.xib** is just a `GLKView`.

My **MainViewController.xib** has a `GLKView` subview.

In my **MainViewController.xib** I have a `GLKView` with an outlet:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GLKView *theSubView;
```

Then in **MainViewController.m** I do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    subviewController = [[CustomOpenGLController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomOpenGLController" bundle:nil];
    subviewController.view.frame = _theSubView.frame;
    [subviewController setView:self.theSubView];
    [self.theSubView setNeedsDisplay];
    [subviewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

This causes `viewDidLoad` of `CustomOpenGLController` to be called which does the following:

**CustomOpenGLController.h**

```
@interface CustomOpenGLController : GLKViewController <GLKViewControllerDelegate, GLKViewDelegate>
{
@private
    GLKBaseEffect *effect;
}

#pragma mark GLKViewControllerDelegate
- (void)glkViewControllerUpdate:(GLKViewController *)controller;

#pragma mark GLKViewDelegate
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end
```

**CustomOpenGLController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");

    EAGLContext *aContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    GLKView *glkView = (GLKView *)self.view;
    glkView.delegate = self;
    glkView.context = aContext;

    glkView.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
    glkView.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat16;
    glkView.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;

    self.delegate = self;
    self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30;

    effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

The problem is the delegates `glkViewControllerUpdate` and `glkView` drawInRect is not called.

If I add `CustomOpenGLController` as a subview (instead of the setView call) then `glkView` drawInRect gets called once.  If use `CustomOpenGLController` as a view all on its own then it all works perfectly.

However I need this `CustomOpenGLController` to be embedded within normal view controllers.

UPDATE

If I modify the `viewDidLoad` for **MainViewController.m** to the following then it works but it only render 1 frame then stops calling `glkView` drawInRect:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad ControllerView");
    subviewController = [[ControllerOpenGLViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ControllerOpenGLViewController" bundle:nil];
    subviewController.view.frame = _theSubView.frame;

    subviewController.view.opaque = NO;
    subviewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.view addSubview:subviewController.view];
    [subviewController.view setNeedsDisplay];

    NSLog(@"Done viewDidLoad ControllerView");
}
```

This oddly renders 1 frame then stops.  Also `glkViewControllerUpdate` is never called.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `CustomOpenGLController` as a child ViewController, yet you never call `addChildViewController` in your `MainViewController` viewDidLoad. Your problem might come from this